# Changing Memory& CPU usage in Windows 7

Tags: windows, memory-management, cpu-usage

I want to test with a windows machine with low performance hard wares. Unfortunately I have a higher end machine. Is there a way to limit the performance of CPU and RAM memory usage? Can I do it through any other software or is there way through windows OS itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use VMWare to limit memory. You won't be able to limit processor speed in your virtual machine but you can assign only 1 core to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try [CPUKiller](http://www.cpukiller.com/) - software for limiting CPU performance.

You can use the truncatememory boot options to limit the amount of memory available usable by Windows. See [BCDEdit /set (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)